# Uploading PDF file from ios to server using Alamofire - PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire

I am not able to upload a pdf file from the ios device to the server(PHP).  I know my PHP code works, because I use it to receive uploads from web clients.  Below is my code:

Function to upload a newly created blank PDFDocument:

```
 let uploadURL  = "https://www.example.com/myUplpoadFile.php"

 @IBAction func createNewFolder(_ sender: Any) {
    print("createNewFolder pressed ...")

    var fileName = nameFolder.text
    fileName = fileName! + ".pdf"
    // Create new PDFDocument
    let newDoc = PDFDocument.init()

    // Write to cache directory
    let newDocURL = generateURLForDocument(nameOfFile: fileName!)
    newDoc.write(to: newDocURL)

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(newDocURL, withName: "file1")
        },
        to: uploadURL,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
}



 // Create URL for PDFDocument to write to memory(Library/Caches/)
func generateURLForDocument(nameOfFile: String) -> URL {

    let cacheDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let urlFile = cacheDir.appendingPathComponent(nameOfFile)

    return urlFile

}
```

PHP (AWS file upload):

```
$tempPath =  $_FILES["file1"]['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]['name'];

$bucketName = 'myAWSBucket';
$folder = 'UploadFiles';
$userId = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$userFolder = 'user_'.$userId;
$userLabBookFolder = 'myBook';

$pathToLabBook = $folder.'/'.$userFolder.'/'.$userLabBookFolder.'/'.$fileName;

try{
    $result = $client -> putObject(array(
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key' => $pathToLabBook,
        'SourceFile' => $tempPath
    ));


    // Remove temp file
    unlink($tempPath);

}catch (S3Exception $e) {
    die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

output from console:

```
 [Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000002292e0> { URL: https://www.example/myUplpoadFile.php } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    268
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Wed, 14 Mar 2018 12:24:04 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    "Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.27"
);
"x-powered-by" =     (
    "PHP/7.0.27"
);
 } }
```

> [Data]: 268
>   bytes[Result]:FAILURE:serializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})) [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 542723043.940, "Initial
>   Response Time": 542723044.323, "Request Completed Time":
>   542723044.539, "Serialization Completed Time": 542723044.540, "Latency": 0.383 secs, "Request Duration": 0.599 secs, "Serialization
>   Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.599 secs } 2018-03-14
>   12:25:04.646785+0000 labbook[13909:1338114] [BoringSSL] Function
>   boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read]
>   SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was
>   cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert 2018-03-14
>   12:25:04.647073+0000 labbook[13909:1338114] [BoringSSL] Function
>   boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read]
>   SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was
>   cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue? do you have any output from the app or webserver to point us in the right direction. Posting a bunch of code and saying something doesn't work does not give us enough information to help you. Please provide details of whats happening when running, any output, warnings or errors.

Comment: please see update console uotput

Comment: It looks like your PHP script does not output anything on success and your Swift code is attempting to convert the (empty) response to a JSON object and finding nothing. although there are 268 bytes of data. try printing the response as a string rather than JSON decoding it

Comment: thanks man appreciate it